# Android - Crop text from image (using openCV or anything else)

Tags: java, android, ocr, tesseract, crop

I'm a beginner and I am trying to make an android module for an OCR process. To optimize the process I'm trying to crop the text part of an image automatically. I've been struggling but i just cannot do it. I found couple tutorials like [this one](https://www.danvk.org/2015/01/07/finding-blocks-of-text-in-an-image-using-python-opencv-and-numpy.html) but it's not in java and my brain just won't work. Any help would be appreciated, i'm still trying to learn. Been researching for couple days already.

Currently using openCV for some post processing to improve accuracy, and to extract data from the image (receipts from some machines) i'm using regular expressions to get relevant data (data,time,machine number 5digits, and some numbers that are 6digits and sometimes it doesnt work, it's all i could come up to for now).

Trying to improve the process as much as possible. If needed i can provide the code but it's a total mess. I've created a sepparate android studio project just for opencv processing.

Sorry for the long text, looking to improve (i'm really a beginner i think). Thank you very much!

Forgot to mention - Using TESSERACT for the OCR process, openCV for image processing. The app is going to be used by some not so tech savvy people, i wanted to use a manual crop tool but it won't be of much use.
All done on device, no internet connection possible.

**Need to crop the text part of an image**

Attached code aswell that creates boxes on text (with a degree of accuracy)

**Still open to suggestions on how to improve the accuracy, thank you!**

```
public Vector<Rect> detectLetters(Mat img){
    Mat img_gray = new Mat();
    Mat img_sobel = new Mat();
    Mat img_threshold = new Mat();
    Mat element = new Mat();
    Mat contourOutput = new Mat();

    Vector<Rect> boundRect = new Vector<>();

    Imgproc.cvtColor(img, img_gray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    Imgproc.Sobel(img_gray, img_sobel, CvType.CV_8U, 1,0,3,1,0,BORDER_DEFAULT);
    Imgproc.threshold(img_sobel, img_threshold, 0, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU+Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);
    element = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, new Size(30,30));
    Imgproc.morphologyEx(img_threshold, img_threshold, 3, element);

    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();
    Imgproc.findContours(img_threshold, contours, contourOutput, 0, 1);
    Iterator<MatOfPoint> iterator = contours.iterator();

    List<MatOfPoint> contours_poly = new ArrayList<>(contours.size());

    for (int i=0; i<contours.size(); i++){
        if(contours.get(i).toArray().length > 100){
            double epsilon = 0.1*Imgproc.arcLength(new MatOfPoint2f(contours.get(1).toArray()),true);
            MatOfPoint2f approx = new MatOfPoint2f();
            Imgproc.approxPolyDP(new MatOfPoint2f(contours.get(1).toArray()),approx,epsilon,true);
            Rect appRect = Imgproc.boundingRect(contours.get(i));

            if(appRect.width > appRect.height);
            boundRect.add(appRect);
        }
    }
    return boundRect;
}
```

Comment: https://www.maketecheasier.com/convert-image-to-text-ocr-android/ ?

Comment: @IshitaSinha Thank you but currently looking to automatically detect text regions.

Answer (score 0):

Is [ML Kit Text Recognition](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/recognize-text) the thing that you need?

Comment: I came across that aswell, can't remember if i haven't tried using it or there were some issues with using it.

The process cannot be done in Cloud, and it's not a personal project, so perhaps prices and limits are included, not sure. Will try and look into it, Thanks!

Comment: You can also check this project [Mobile Vision Text Recognition API](https://developers.google.com/vision/android/text-overview) it is predecessor of ML Kit.

Comment: Alright will look into it thanks. Although i think there's still some limitations on using  google vision / derives of it.